State transition in SwiftUI by scrolling in onAppear can be lost
If you use the onAppear method to scroll to a SwiftUI view with the help of a ScrollViewProxy, this can lead to the loss of the state transition in the view when using published values of an ObservableObject.
The problem occurs in all current iOS SDKs (17.5 / 18.0), on the iOS simulators and on real devices.
Here is a code reduced to the minimum to reproduce the problem.
SwiftUI view:
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    @Namespace private var state2ID

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    if viewModel.state2 {
                        VStack {
                            Text("State2 is set")
                        }
                        .id(state2ID)
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation {
                                scrollProxy.scrollTo(state2ID)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("State1: \(viewModel.state1)")
                        Text("State1 changes from 'false -> true -> false' when the button is pressed.")
                            .font(.footnote)
                    }

                    Button("Toggle States") {
                        viewModel.toggleStates()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)

                    Color.teal
                        .frame(height: 900)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

View model:
@MainActor
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var state1 = false
    @Published private(set) var state2 = false

    private var stateToggle = false

    func toggleStates() {
        Task { @MainActor in
            state1 = true
            defer {
                // This change never becomes visible in the view!
                // state1 will be improperly shown as 'true' when this method returns while it actually is 'false'.
                print("Resetting state1")
                state1 = false
            }

            stateToggle.toggle()

            if stateToggle {
                withAnimation {
                    state2 = true
                }
            } else {
                state2 = false
            }
        }
    }
}

When you press the "Toggle States" button, the text for state1 shows “State1: true” when the task completes, but it should show “State1: false” because state1 is set to false in the task of toggleStates.
At this point, the actual values of the view model and the values displayed in the view are no longer in sync.
If you remove the scrollProxy.scrollTo(state2ID) call in the onAppear method, the problem does not occur. It therefore appears to be triggered by the scrolling process.
This seems very unexpected and a bug, or am I missing something fundamental?
Any idea why this is the case and how to use the scrollTo method of a ScrollViewProxy object so that this error does not occur?

This problem may be a timing issue related to the view model performing changes withAnimation.
I would suggest, it is better if a view model is not concerned with presentation details such as animation.
In any case, you can get it working by taking the animation controls out of the view model and putting them in the view instead:
1. In ContentViewModel, comment out the withAnimation
// ContentViewModel

if stateToggle {
    // withAnimation { //  HERE
        state2 = true
    // }
} else {
    state2 = false
}

Of course, you could simplify the code while you're at it:
stateToggle.toggle()
state2 = stateToggle

...or you could scrap stateToggle and just toggle state2 instead. This might help to make the view model a bit less convoluted.
2. In ContentView, add an .animation modifier to the top-level VStack inside the ScrollView
// ContentView

ScrollView(.vertical) {
    VStack(spacing: 15) {
        // ...
    }
    .padding()
    .animation(.default, value: viewModel.state2) //  HERE
}

This gives a slide animation when revealing as well as when hiding. If you want to suppress the animation for hide (like you had it before) then you could use a ternary operator in the .animation modifier:
.animation(viewModel.state2 ? .default : nil, value: viewModel.state2)


Some very good suggestions!
Your added change to your answer to not use animation when hiding the view was also exactly what your answer was missing and what I wanted to ask about.
The use of stateToggle was for demonstration purposes only, the actual code does not make use of this mechanism.
The same applies to state2which in reality is not a Bool value.

Could using the animation modifier have animation related side effects on other subviews in the VStack?

@ITGuy It will only affect views whose appearance depend on the flag state2. Compared to using withAnimation as you were doing before, I would expect it to behave the same.

Like you, I also suspect a timing problem that leads to the behavior originally described. I think we agree that the original code should not cause state changes to be lost in the view, even if you use a withAnimation in a view model.
I haven't seen Apple mention anywhere that you shouldn't do this for the reasons described.
Ultimately, your solution helps to avoid the problem, even if it doesn't fully explain the problem, so I'll mark your answer as a solution.

@ITGuy Thanks for accepting the answer! I also haven't seen any docs saying that withAnimation should not be used outside of a view. But consider the case of where you want to change the animation style, perhaps to .spring with all sorts of parameters. Imho, that kind of presentation detail definitely doesn't belong in the view model.

From a software architecture point of view, I absolutely agree with you. Animation logic doesn't really belong in the view model.
